# What are the problems with MySQL that cause it to get bad press?

Tags: mysql

I'm primarily a PostgreSQL user and I frequently hear about MySQL getting bad press (much like PHP). However, I don't actually know or understand why this happens. So I'm curious, what are the large problems with MySQL that cause developers to prefer other database solutions, and how real are the problems in the current releases?

Comment: What bad press exactly? What problems? You'll need to back this up with some reference material

Comment: I can't back it up because literally it's statements like "Oh, you're using MySQL. Well that's your problem" -- I'm trying to see how founded these statements actually are.

Comment: I think it's a shame this got closed too. I understand it's a touchy subject but there ARE differences between implementation, and this naturally means that some implementations do things better than something else.

Answer (score 4):

I read something about this just yesterday in [Phil Greenspun's blog](http://blogs.law.harvard.edu/philg/2011/01/18/rdbms-course-update/):

> Now that MySQL is 16 years old, I was surprised at the things that they’ve yet to accomplish. For example, the C in ACID is “Consistency”, i.e., being able to enforce rules in the SQL data model and using the RDBMS as a last line of defense against programmer mistakes. Yet MySQL silently fails to enforce any CHECK constraint. Similarly, when students would GROUP BY column_a and then SELECT column_b (where column_b had multiple values within each group), instead of raising an error as Oracle, Postgres, or SQL Server would, MySQL happily picks a column_b value at random and includes it. I don’t understand why people use it.

Also, the [MySQL Gotchas](http://sql-info.de/mysql/gotchas.html) page is a classic list.